Tried installing new extensions but now I get an error
I tried installing new extensions, however it timed out on my site.
Now when I try and go to my backend cvi home with the dashlets, I am receiving a network error: unable to reach server.
I also receive an error when trying to go into contact records. When I turned debug on, this is what I received:
SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`uf_group_id` AS `uf_group_id`, `uf_group_id_1`.`title` AS `uf_group_id.title`, `uf_group_id_1`.`name` AS `uf_group_id.name`, `uf_group_id_1`.`group_type` AS `uf_group_id.group_type`, GROUP_CONCAT(`fields`.`field_name` SEPARATOR "") AS `field_names`, GROUP_CONCAT(`fields`.`label` ORDER BY `fields`.`weight` SEPARATOR "") AS `field_labels` FROM civicrm_uf_join a LEFT JOIN `civicrm_uf_group` `uf_group_id_1` ON `a`.`uf_group_id` = `uf_group_id_1`.`id` LEFT JOIN (`civicrm_uf_field` `fields`) ON `a`.`uf_group_id` = `fields`.`uf_group_id` AND `fields`.`is_active` = "1" WHERE (`a`.`module` = "Contact Summary") AND (`uf_group_id_1`.`is_active` = "1") GROUP BY `a`.`id` [nativecode=1055 ** 'ajybnmfy_adcid.a.uf_group_id' isn't in GROUP BY]

DebugInfo   SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`uf_group_id` AS `uf_group_id`, `uf_group_id_1`.`title` AS `uf_group_id.title`, `uf_group_id_1`.`name` AS `uf_group_id.name`, `uf_group_id_1`.`group_type` AS `uf_group_id.group_type`, GROUP_CONCAT(`fields`.`field_name` SEPARATOR "") AS `field_names`, GROUP_CONCAT(`fields`.`label` ORDER BY `fields`.`weight` SEPARATOR "") AS `field_labels` FROM civicrm_uf_join a LEFT JOIN `civicrm_uf_group` `uf_group_id_1` ON `a`.`uf_group_id` = `uf_group_id_1`.`id` LEFT JOIN (`civicrm_uf_field` `fields`) ON `a`.`uf_group_id` = `fields`.`uf_group_id` AND `fields`.`is_active` = "1" WHERE (`a`.`module` = "Contact Summary") AND (`uf_group_id_1`.`is_active` = "1") GROUP BY `a`.`id` [nativecode=1055 ** 'ajybnmfy_adcid.a.uf_group_id' isn't in GROUP BY]

Can anybody help me with this?

After updating civicrm and running db update, this issue is no longer occurring.

civi isn't fully sql group-by compliant. You'll need to turn that off in your database's SQL_MODE. See the part about ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#mysql-configuration

I have tried to run this, this morning, but I still recieve the same error. Although ni didnt run it as GLOBAL, due to no permissions on then hosted server, I removed GLOBAL and ran it successfully., yet the error remains

Ask your hosting provider how to set sql_mode globally on their systems.

The hosting provider refused to run this sql due to it being unsafe for the rest of the server. However after updating civicrm it is working fine now.
